# Can a level shifting circuit shift voltage the other way around?

Tags: fpga, servo, level-shifting

I'm working on a project where I use an FPGA and connect it to multiple servos (called AX-12), which are connected in a daisy chain. Each servos has a unique ID so them being connected in a daisy chain is not a problem.
The FPGA transmits commands to the servos and after that the servos respond by transmitting their own packets (called a status packet, according to the datasheet). **I want to focus on the respond part in this question**.

[image: AX-12 servos connected in a daisy chain]

The "CM-5" you see in the picture is replaced by the FPGA in my project.

According to the datasheet ([which you can find here](http://www.hizook.com/files/users/3/AX-12_Robotis_Dynamixel_Servo_UserGuide.pdf)):

> To operate the Dynamixel actuators, the main controller must support
>   TTL level half duplex UART.

For the main controller' I'm using a DE2 evaluation board by Altera (later to be replaced by the DE0-Nano). This board's outputs for '1' is 3.3V.
While 3.3V works for TTL, I found out that the servos respond better when they receive 5V.

To do this, I use this level shifting circuit:
[image]

So for the transmission part, all is well. The FPGA outputs the '1' as 3.3V and the servos receive it as 5V, which is good.

My question is about the voltage when I receive the packets from the servos. I assume (haven't checked) that the servos transmit the status packet bits in 5V. 
Does the level shifting circuit get the 5V and shift it back to 3.3V? And the 0V to, obviously, 0V? If so, how does it work?

If you look in the datasheet, you will see that the manufacturer says you should use a buffer with a pull-up resistor to 5V. I have tried using that buffer and it did no go so well. So what I'm also asking is, will that level shifting circuit use as a buffer?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does the level shifting circuit get the 5V and shift it back to 3.3V?

Yes, that circuit works bidirectionally although it might be a good idea to have a pull-down resistor on the 3.3V logic line to 0 volts (see later on counter argument).

When the 5V side is at 5V, R1 pulls up the 3V3 side via the base-emitter junction (a forward biased diode). When the 5V side is at 0V, the base-collector region becomes forward biased and this pulls the base down to approximately 0.7 volts and the emitter (with the pull-down resistor mentioned) would fall to 0 volts.

However, you could make a case for the transistor working (albeit with reduced beta) in an upside-down mode (i.e. collector and emitter swap places). This would naturally tend towards thinking about a pull-up on the 3V3 line. I'd rather use a MOSFET version: -

[image]

It's a little more clear cut on how the 5V side drags the 3V3 side down to 0V - it uses the body diode in the MOSFET to achieve this and therefore doesn't need a pull-down on the 3V3 side.

Comment: Thanks! I have some questions about things not clear to me. Some may be about technical terms because English is not my native language and those terms are not ones I always understand.

Comment: 1. "R1 pulls up the 3V3 side". What does that mean? That because of R1, the 3.3V side gets a voltage of 3.3V?
2. If the answer to 1 is true - if the base gets a voltage of 3.3V due to R1, and there is a voltage drop of 0.65-0.7V in Vbe (Vbe = Vb - Ve), doesn't that mean that Ve = Vb - Vbe = 3.3 - 0.7 = 2.6V?
3. "base-collector region becomes forward biased" - does that mean there is a short between the base and the collector? That's because the transistor is in saturation?

Comment: 1) R1 is connected to the 3V3 line via diode that is naturally forward biased in all circumstances when the 3V3 line is loaded. When unloaded (or very lightly loaded) the 3V3 line naturally sits around 2.6 volts. That's the action of a pull-up and although at 2.6 volts, this is more than sufficient to represent a logic 1 lvel on a 3V3 system. 2) Aha (!) I see you have worked this out for yourself!!! Good man.

Comment: 4. I'm embarrassed to ask this, but, how does that pull-down resistor work? Does all of the current go to the ground because of the pull-down resistor, meaning the FPGA gets no current at all?
And wow you answer fast! Thanks again.

Comment: I'm still debating the pros and cons of a pull-down versus a pull-up for the 3V3 line. If using a pull-down, it has to be "light" and significantly higher in resistance than R1 else a potential divider will be formed so, something like 100 kohms would be OK. Any current into the input of an FPGA will be nano amps at best and so you can ignore its loading effect.

Comment: Hi, I know this is a an old question but I was hoping you could help me with something here. I started thinking about the other circuit you suggested, with the N-MOS BSS138, and I just couldn't understand why it works. I simulated it, and came up with this: https://ibb.co/gBqSTe
https://ibb.co/mkSJZK. One is when I receive 5V and the other when I receive 0V.

Comment: I don't understand, from what it seems, Vgs will always be 0V, and Vth = 1.3 according to the datasheet of the BSS138, so how exactly does this work, and what role does the diode play here? I know that these diodes have a voltage drop of about 1V, but I just don't understand the "chain of events" in this circuit. Thank you!!!

Comment: I would also like to know if this is the correct way to simulate this circuit and having the Rload simulate an FPGA input.

Comment: If I were you I’d consider asking this as a proper question so that you get a fuller answer from more folk. Bit busy at the moment.